# Jquery-Cycle Is hovering above my fixed nav bar, how would I make it go behind it like everything else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle

On my website [www.staygold-design.com](http://staygold-design.com) I have a fixed nav bar that floats above all the content.

I have a jquery cycle slide show going on in the second section (***click portfolio and scroll the page right to see what I'm trying to explain***) and it seems to float above the nav bar.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use z-index to change the layer precedence.

```css
#slideshowcontainer {
    z-index: 5;
}
#fixednav {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

I've just tested in Firebug an it works. You may need to add `position: relative` to `#slideshowcontainer` for this to work in all browsers though.